# Studying Torah while lying on a bed?

Tags: torah-study, technology

I often watch Shiurim and use Mi Yodeya while lying (sometimes sitting) on my bed. What are the parameters for one's position while studying Torah? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: From pashut pshat of Shema,ושננתם לבניך ודברת בם בשבתך בביתך ובלכתך בדרך ובשכבך ובקומך ,that even laying down,in fact Bais Shammi said Shema laying down,but as mentioned the gemara brings down the Torah should be learned in awe

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I saw [this](http://www.ravaviner.com/2009/03/learning-torah-while-laying-in-bed.html) interesting answer by [Rav Aviner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shlomo_Aviner) to a similar question:

> Q: Is it permissible to learn Torah while laying in bed or on a couch?
>
> A: One must learn Torah in awe, fear and trembling ([Berachot 22a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=22&format=pdf)). This idea is also found in the Mishnah Sotah (9:15) that we should learn while standing for the honor of Torah (see [Megillah 21a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=11&daf=21&format=pdf)). In truth, it is proper to learn Torah only while standing but we do not have the strength and we therefore, learn while seated. But even while seated, we must learn in an upright position and with an awe of holiness. One should certainly not learn while lying down. But if someone is sick or tired and needs to lie down, it is permissible to learn while doing so. In other words, when we learn, we do not need to lie down but when we lie down, we certainly need to learn.

Comment: Adam, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for bringing this source  to bear! Please [edit] this post per our [quotation guideline](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/75/how-should-i-cite-an-answer-elsewhere/76#76): Make it explicit whom you're citing, and replace the copy/paste of his work with a summary of the pertinent points in your own words, using quotation selectively when the original language is especially important.

Comment: I've edited your post a bit to start off. See the links in Isaac's comments for more info.